# Anomaly in sentiment analysis done by IBM Watson Discovery

Tags: sentiment-analysis, watson-discovery

When I give a positive comment document, Discovery is correctly categorising it as positive sentiment document.

But when I give a document with both positive and negative comments, Discovery is categorising it as positive sentiment document.

Again, when I give a negative comment document (Eg: not skilled), Discovery is categorising it as neutral sentiment document.

Is there any settings or configuration in Discovery by which this anomaly can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You may need more text for it to fully grasp the sentiment - it also may not be perfect, things like sarcasm, double negatives, etc... are sometimes hard for sentiment analysis algorithms.

Two things I can suggest:
1) Provide the full example you are trying to process, as well as the output Discovery is giving your for sentiment - this way we can validate if it's a bug or something else.
2) Look at the score we are assigning for sentiment analysis - even though it's been labeled as Positive or Negative, their may be a lower threshold on the score you could use

(I'm a Watson Discovery employee)